# Spark Kafka Integration using receiver with WAL

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I was reading below blog in Databricks

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/30/improvements-to-kafka-integration-of-spark-streaming.html

While explaining the process how spark kafka integration works using receiver with WAl , it says

> 1.The Kafka data is continuously received by Kafka Receivers running in the Spark workers/executors. **This used the high-level consumer API**
>   of Kafka.
>
> 2.The received data is stored in Spark’s worker/executor memory as well as to the WAL (replicated on HDFS). The Kafka **Receiver updated
>   Kafka’s offsets to Zookeeper only after the data has been persisted to
>   the log.**

Now my doubt is how a high level consumer can update offset in zookeeper , as high level consumer does not handle offset, it is handled by zookeeper. So once we read a message from kafka using zookeeper then zookeeper automatically update the offset.

Comment: You're reading obsolete docs. Kafka is already a log, so it makes little sense to front it with WAL. That's reason why the `DirectConsumer` was created. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. yes you are correct. but I was trying to understand the design of how receiver with WAL works.

Answer (score 0):

So when a consumer retrieves data from a particular topic in kafka it is the responsibility of the consumer to update the offsets in zookeeper. So when you use a custom kafka consumer it has an inbuild kafka API( org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.* does that )that will update the offsets once you receive the data from that particular topic.

In case of that receiver based approach in spark it uses Kafka's high level API to update the offsets in zookeeper.